# getjson problem

Tags: jquery, getjson

```
var items;
$.getJSON('calender_service.php?command=calender', function(data) {
    items = data;
    var name = [];
    var date_start = [];

    var date_start_time = "";
    $.each(items, function(key, val) {
        name[key] = val.name;
        date_start[key] = val.date_start;
        events[key] = ""+""+","+val.date_start.split("-")+","+val.date_start_time+","+val.date_end_time+","+val.name+","+val.status+"";
    });

    alert(events);  
});
```

please help me, not getting the variable value events, outside the getjson method.

Answer (score 0):

In order to have it outside the callback function you must have the events variable defined as a global one (i.e. try defining it before making the json call).

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var items;
var events;

$.getJSON('calender_service.php?command=calender', function(data) {
    items = data;
    var name = [];
    var date_start = [];
    var date_start_time = "";
    $.each(items, function(key, val) {
        name[key] = val.name;
        date_start[key] = val.date_start;
        events[key] = "" + "" + "," + val.date_start.split("-") + "," + val.date_start_time + "," + val.date_end_time + "," + val.name + "," + val.status + "";
    });
});

alert(events);
```

Answer (score 0):

Define events as a variable in the outer scope.

```
var events = {};
var  items;
 $.getJSON('calender_service.php?command=calender', function(data) {
  items=data;
 var name=[];
  ...
  ..
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Define "events" outside the $.each loop. For example after date_start.